# kohana 3 incorporate file validate in orm

Tags: kohana

I cant figure out how to add  file validation code to the orm model

As the code is now the text inputs are validated in the orm, but the file has no validation on it at all. I was wondering if it was possible to merge the file validation in the 'profile' model where I have the text validation?

Here is the code in my controller

```
public function action_public_edit()
{
    $content = View::factory('profile/public_edit')
        ->bind('user', $user)
        ->bind('profile', $profile)
        ->bind('errors', $errors);
    $user = Auth::instance()->get_user();
    $profile = $user->profiles;
    $this->template->content = $content;
    if ($_POST)
    {
        if ($profile->values($_POST)->check())
        {
            $picture = Upload::save($_FILES['profile_picture']);
            // Resize, sharpen, and save the image
            Image::factory($picture)
            ->resize(100, 100, Image::WIDTH)
            ->save();
            $profile->profile_picture = basename($picture);
            $profile->save();
            $redirect = "profile/private";
            Request::instance()->redirect($redirect);
        }
        else
        {
            $errors = $profile->validate()->errors('profile/public_edit');
        }
    }
}
```

And the ORM model

```
protected $_belongs_to = array('user' => array());

protected $_rules = array(
'first_name' => array(
    'not_empty' => NULL,
),
'last_name' => array(
    'not_empty' => NULL,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `check()` if you  `save()` later - save will do the checking and throw `ORM_Validation_Exception` if validation is not passed. I suggest to create a function in your model for saving - move the lines after `check()` to this model. In controller you'll only need to write:

```
if ($this->request->method() === 'POST')
{
   $errors = $profile->upload('profile_picture');
   if (empty($errors))
   {
       try 
       {
          $profile->your_save_function();
          $this->request->redirect('profile/private');
       }
       catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
       {
          $errors = $e->errors('profile');
       }
   }
}
```

In your model:

```
public function your_save_function()
{
    // Do your stuff before uploading the picture 

    // Save the model
    $this->save();
}

    public function upload($filename)
    {

        // Set the default upload directory
        Upload::$default_directory = 'your_path';

        // Validate the file first
        $validation = Validation::factory($_FILES)
                ->rules($filename, array(
                    array('not_empty'),
                    array('Upload::not_empty'),
                    array('Upload::valid'),
                    array('Upload::type', array(':value', array('your_valid_extensions'))),
                    array('Upload::size', array(':value', 'your_max_size')),
                ));

        // Validate and upload OK
        if ($validation->check())
        {
            $picture = Upload::save($_FILES[$filename]);

            // Resize, sharpen, and save the image
            Image::factory($picture)
                ->resize(100, 100, Image::WIDTH)
                ->save();
            $this->profile_picture = basename($picture);
        }
        else
        {
            return $validation->errors('upload');
        }
    }
```

Much simpler and cleaner code.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the actual validation code will look like in the model for files in my example, If it even should be done in the model.

Comment: Thanks I will try this and let you know how it worked

Thanks again